# What does "ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED" mean in Chrome error code?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, http, error-handling

That error message logged to the chrome console from a long-pending request after around 15 minutes.

It looks client-side error because server processing still worked.

I did not find any article related to this error message.

can any buddy let me know how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Jainik Patel Nice correction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the chromium source I think it means that a spdy ping timed out.

```
...
    {net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, "http.response.empty"},
    {net::ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED, "spdy.ping_failed"},
    {net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR, "spdy.protocol"},
...
```

Source https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/components/domain_reliability/util.cc#48

Chrome sends such pings before and after a request.

Source https://groups.google.com/d/msg/spdy-dev/HFjAbFRd-N0/p-Edt-lneGsJ

Comment: This is not an answer, it is just info!