# ERROR net::ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED: when installing VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

so i wanted to install some extension, and i got this error notification that said net::ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED: Download: net::ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAIL .

this error resulting in stuck when installing extension.

how can i solve this? it seems that this problem is related to out of date web browser but my VSCode and Microsoft Edge are all already up to date, and i dont have any other web browser.

can someone help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/naTyc.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f9mg.png

i have tried changing my dns into google dns and it doesnt change a thing.

Comment: related: [What does "ERR_HTTP2_PING_FAILED" mean in Chrome error code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59450447/11107541) (VS Code is built using Electron, which uses Chromium) Are there any "oddities" of your network setup? VPN?